# How to download Swift Playgrounds iPad app?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift-playground

I see so many articles of people who have tried Swift Playgrounds app on iPad for development, that Apple announced in WWDC. But I am not able to find an ipa/download option from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com).
The public version is coming out in July, but I am not sure if a registered developer (with a developer account) can get access to it right now.

Comment: probably need to get it through the developer portal and need a developer account for preview

Comment: You have to install the IOS 10 Beta, oh yeah and its pretty sweet btw.

Comment: @Haligen cool, so it will just show up in appstore after i install iOS 10 beta?

Comment: You need to install iOS 10 beta on your iPad.  To do that, you don't even need a Mac.  With your iPad, go to https://developer.apple.com/download/. You'll need to log in.  Open iOS 10 beta link and click `Download` next to `Configuration Profile`.  This will allow you to install iOS 10 beta over the air.  Swift Playgrounds is preinstalled in iOS 10 beta.

Comment: It will automatically be installed when you install 10 beta on an iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the iOS 10 Beta 1 (at least, if someone reads this in the future).

They have a "special" App Store in the betas, for the removable stock apps.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is probably that the app is called "Playgrounds", not including "Swift"!  So in spotlight, type playgrounds or look for it on your home screen...
(Not something I noticed right away; they should have told us!)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Sign up for the Apple Beta Software Program](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/welcome). You can use your apple ID to sign up! Pretty easy stuff.
2. Backup your iOS device using iTunes (in my case it was an iPad mini 64GB). To do this, plug your iPad into your PC/Mac running iTunes, right click your device, and press "Back Up". **DON'T SKIP THIS STEP** -- this will ensure that if the iOS 10 Beta 1 fails on your iPad, you can revert back to a stable release of iOS!
3. On your iPad (**IN SAFARI**... tried this in Chrome and it didn't work), go to [beta.apple.com/profile](http://beta.apple.com/profile) and download what apple calls the "Configuration Profile". This will install the platform needed to install iOS 10 Beta 1 on your device. (installer for an installer...inception!)
4. Once the "Configuration Profile" is installed on your iOS device, you can go to `Settings > General > Software` Update to install iOS 10 Beta 1. iOS 10 Beta 1 contains Swift Playgrounds, like @saxophone mentioned